# Taking derivative of a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, derivative, calculus

I have function and need to take partial derivatives respect to its two variables.

The function is:

[image: sum over r, p, q]

Since I am not really good at math, I need some help to know the following derivatives:

[image: df/dp and df/dq]

Comment: i am just curious - what language is that?

Comment: @pm100 latex...

Comment: I thought it would automatically compile latex here.

Comment: p and q are matrices, right?

Comment: Vectors? What is the transposed of p(i)? This is unusual notation.

Comment: sorry, it is my bad. They are matrices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let F(p,q) be

```
F(p,q) = sum(j, [ r(j) - sum(i, p(i,j)*q(i,j)) ]^2 )
```

Then dF/dp is the matrix A formed by elements

```
A(i,j) = 2 * [r(j) - sum(k, p(k,j)*q(k,j))] * (-q(i,j))
```

dF/dq is the matrix B formed by elements

```
B(i,j) = 2 * [r(j) - sum(k, p(k,j)*q(k,j))] * (-p(i,j))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the index k?

Comment: That is just a name. You can use another name. (Note: We cannot use `i` there because that is already used to index A(i,j) or B(i,j))